# Python - Generating all combinations of Hexadecimal values

Tags: python, string, for-loop, hex

I have an Encryption key which is 32-bits in Hexadecimal format. But I'm only given 22 bits. I have to find the Plaintext. My thought process is to do a brute-force attack and find the other 10 bits. I am also given the Ciphertext. The Encryption used is AES in 128-bit ECB Mode. I am using Python, but I just started learning it so I am not an expert yet.

My approach is to take the 22-bit key and concatenate the other 10 bits, feed that into AES along with the Ciphertext and Decrypt to check if one of the resulting phrases resembles a proper sentence. The only part that I am stuck on is generating the 10 bit Hexadecimal string.

This is the output that I want:

```
0000000000
0000000001
0000000002
...
000000000F
...
FFFFFFFFFF
```

What is an approach I could use to do this? I tried making a dictionary and assigning numerical values to all Hexadecimal values but I am stuck on how to write a loop that could give the sequence I want as an output.

Comment: So you want a way to generate strings of length 10 of all possible hexadecimal numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def gen_all_hex():
    i = 0
    while i < 16**10:
        yield "{:010X}".format(i)
        i += 1

for s in gen_all_hex():
    print(s)
```

Result:

```
0000000000
0000000001
0000000002
0000000003
0000000004
0000000005
0000000006
0000000007
0000000008
0000000009
000000000A
000000000B
000000000C
000000000D
000000000E
000000000F
0000000010
0000000011
0000000012
0000000013
0000000014
0000000015
0000000016
0000000017
0000000018
0000000019
000000001A
...
```

Note that it's going to take a long time to iterate through all 1,099,511,627,776 values.

Comment: Addendum: I considered doing `for i in range(16**10):` instead of a while loop, but then it isn't cross-version compatible. You'd get `OverflowError: range() result has too many items` in Python 2.7.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do. Could you explain what the "yield "{:010x}".format(i).upper()" does? Because I want to understand what the code is doing before using it.

Comment: Ok. "{:010x}" is a format specifier. When you call `format(i)` on it, it produces a string version of `i` according to the parameters in the specifier. the first 0 means "pad the string with zeroes if it isn't the maximum width". the 10 after that means "the maximum width is 10". The x means "convert this number to hexadecimal". The trailing `upper` call converts the number to upper case. [`yield`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do) takes the value and passes it up into the `for s in gen_all_hex():` scope so we can print it.

Comment: In hindsight, the `upper` call isn't strictly necessary if you use `X` instead of `x`... I always forget both options exist.

Answer (score 5):

```
from itertools import product

print(map(''.join, product('0123456789ABCDEF', repeat=2)))
```

`repeat=2` is for demo purposes, obviously increase that to 10.

For Python 3, if you actually want to see things printed, use `list(map(...))`.

Output:

```
['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0D', '0E', '0F', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '1A', '1B', '1C', '1D', '1E', '1F', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '2A', '2B', '2C', '2D', '2E', '2F', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '3A', '3B', '3C', '3D', '3E', '3F', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '4A', '4B', '4C', '4D', '4E', '4F', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '5A', '5B', '5C', '5D', '5E', '5F', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '6A', '6B', '6C', '6D', '6E', '6F', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '7A', '7B', '7C', '7D', '7E', '7F', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89', '8A', '8B', '8C', '8D', '8E', '8F', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99', '9A', '9B', '9C', '9D', '9E', '9F', 'A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B9', 'BA', 'BB', 'BC', 'BD', 'BE', 'BF', 'C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'CA', 'CB', 'CC', 'CD', 'CE', 'CF', 'D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5', 'D6', 'D7', 'D8', 'D9', 'DA', 'DB', 'DC', 'DD', 'DE', 'DF', 'E0', 'E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'E4', 'E5', 'E6', 'E7', 'E8', 'E9', 'EA', 'EB', 'EC', 'ED', 'EE', 'EF', 'F0', 'F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4', 'F5', 'F6', 'F7', 'F8', 'F9', 'FA', 'FB', 'FC', 'FD', 'FE', 'FF']
```

Comment: Very elegant solution